# Why are all double-underscore variables mangled in class methods

Tags: python

Edit: Both current answers talk about the fact that there is mangling inside classes.  My question is about values inside class methods - note that the parsing in the method scope is different from the class scope, or `__CLASS` would be printable.

---

This seems to be the case in python 2.7 and 3.6.

For example, this code

```
__GLOBAL = 'global'
_Bar__MANGLED_GLOBAL = 'mangled global'

class Bar(object):
    __CLASS = 'class'

    def baz(self):
        __LOCAL = 'local'
        try:
            print __LOCAL
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        try:
            print __CLASS
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        try:
            print __GLOBAL
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        try:
            print __MANGLED_GLOBAL
        except Exception as e:
            print e

Bar().baz()
```

Will give

```
local
global name '_Bar__CLASS' is not defined
global name '_Bar__GLOBAL' is not defined
mangled global
```

I understand the logic when there is an `other.__x`, or needing a class-level `__foo` to equate to `self.__foo`, but this seems like an oversight, where anything inside the class scope is automatically rewritten.

Comment: It's probably related to the complexity of the implementation. There was no perceived *need* for unmangled local variables that would have justified making the distinction.

Comment: It's not possible, in general, to tell whether a given name lookup is going to apply to (an instance of) the current class at runtime.  The mangling is therefore applied to all names.

Comment: @jasonharper I don't think that's quite right. The issue is not that one can't tell if, in `x.__foo` , `x` is an instance of the current class or not. `__FOO` is clearly not an attribute lookup, because there is no `.` involved. Whether such a name might refer to the same object as an attribute doesn't really matter, either, since name mangling is designed to avoid overriding inherited attributes. Local variables aren't affected by inheritance.

Comment: Even if it *was* an oversight, the cost of "fixing" it could also outweight the benefit. Is anybody really that desperate for double-underscore-prefixed local names?

Comment: @chepner  See my answer below, full name of mangling in python is `private name mangling`, which is for all names in class.

Comment: @LiuXiMin I did; you explain *that* all private names are mangled (which the OP has already observed) but not *why*.

Comment: @chepner Maybe sometimes the rule can just be treated as why, though it is not indeed. I am also happy if someone can explain the real why.

Answer (score 3):

This was not an oversight. In fact, private globals used to be specifically advertised in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node67.html#SECTION0010600000000000000000):

> There is now limited support for class-private identifiers. Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is now textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard of the syntactic position of the identifier, so it can be used to define class-private instance and class variables, methods, **as well as globals**, and even to store instance variables private to this class on instances of *other* classes.

Without specific references, like a mailing list conversation or something, we can only speculate as to why it was designed this way. (I checked the commit history, but the [original commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ff077b0949791c6b699cb179749d929a9fdc98a) includes no justification for design choices.) We can speculate that it was to enable things like private globals, but we can also speculate that it was just easiest to implement it this way and that the implementers wouldn't have been swayed by the prospect of private globals if other options were easier. It would certainly have been a lot harder to implement name mangling in a way that only affected the class's instance and class attributes.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: at first, I didn't really answer the question, but according to the clues, I found the real answer at the end, so please be patient and read until the end. **In short, mangling is for all the names that appear in the class.**

Python class can not have real private attribute, prefix `__` is for `private` purpose.

I have seen the below suggestion:

> But try to avoid the `__private` form. I never use it. Trust me. If you use it, you **WILL** regret it later.

and:

> Forms `__private` just trigger a [private name mangling](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411011411/http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) whose purpose is to prevent accidental namespace collisions in subclasses: `MyClass.__private` just becomes `MyClass._MyClass__private`.

[Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python-naming](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411011411/http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#naming)

I looked [private name mangling](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411011411/http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) and according to it, mangling is for all `names` in class:

> **Private name mangling:** When **an identifier** that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a ***private name*** of that class.

So, It seems that mangling is for all the names that appear in class.That is why all double-underscore variables are mangled in class methods.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your argument.  It is true they don't have true private variables (just mangled), but how is that related to the second half of your answer, or my question?

Comment: @Cireo you may want to the link I share.

Comment: Why do you write that "mangling is for all the names that appear in the class", while the links you provide clearly state that it only applies to names that start with at least two underscores and do not end with at least two underscores?

Comment: @wovano yes, you are right. and i am not wrong too. But i guess i didn't express it well. my point is that mangling is for all the names that appear in the class, even those not defined in class. and of course, mangling has its own rule: only applies to names that start with at least two underscores and do not end with at least two underscores. 

Python will try mangling all the names which used in class. sorry for my poor english writing.